# Base table or view not found in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, view, laravel-5.1

> QueryException in Connection.php line 655:
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doctor_info.hospital_categories' doesn't exist (SQL: `select * from hospital_categories`)

[image]

My Table name is `hospitalcategory`, but when I visit this page it give me these errors.

I run `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan cache:clear`, and `php artisan config:clear` commands, but this error cannot resolved.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: It's because you're attempting to access a table that doesn't exist. Did you push the migration to the database after you defined the migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, your table name seems "hospital_category" and Laravel is querying for "hospital_categories".

Laravel, by default, pluralize table names. If you don't like, you need to specify your table name manually in the model (e.g.):

```
class YourModel extends Model {
    public $table = "hospital_category";
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. I change my table name categories instead of hospital_category and it works as fine